# Magento 2 Order Edit return an error "The requested qty is not available"

Tags: php, knockout.js, magento2, magento2.4

By default behavior of Magento 2.4.2 , when admin tries to edit an order from backend an error message saying "The requested qty is not available" is visible if one of the ordered items has a salable qty of 0 and and default quantity 1. This disallows the admin from editing the order. Is there any way I could remove this validation and continue editing the order as normal such that the message is visible only if I try updating the product with zero salable qty.
[Click to see attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C04v0.png)

When trying to edit an order, we expect the order QTY can be edit successfully. But the result was if anyone of the item in that order is not available or salable QTY is zero we can't edit the order.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you use an additional extension for edit orders, check the extension configuration for this something like 'Validate Inventory'.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).